# I want to reduce height of drop down after it opens

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I want to reduce the height of a drop down after it open. I can't change `CSS` of main elements. I want to use classes and ids that are already given to the div. Just wanted to know how to use these classes.

Comment: My link is: http://veepal.co.in/insurance_buddy/car_insurance_quote/

Comment: I want to reduce height of "Year of manufacture" in car details step.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)